# How do i get the name (or id) on an widget which was created with Gtk2::Builder?

Tags: perl, gtk, gtkbuilder

I am converting an app from using [Gtk2::GladeXML](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Gtk2%3a%3aGladeXML) to [Gtk2::Builder](http://gtk2-perl.sourceforge.net/doc/pod/Gtk2/Builder.html). When getting all widgets with

```
@widgets = $glade_object->get_widget_prefix('')
```

I could get the name (set in Glade) of a widget with

```
$widgets[0]->get_widget_name
```

With Gtk2::Builder I fetch all widgets with

```
@widgets = $builder_object->get_objects
```

But `$widgets[0]->get_widget_name` is not known. `$widgets[0]->get_name` just gives me the widget class, e.g. GtkImage.

So my question is: How do i get the name (or id) of an widget which was created with Gtk2::Builder?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: This is a name clash between GtkWidget's and GtkBuildable's `get_name` methods. I don't know how to do this in Perl, but you will need to call GtkBuildable's version somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks @johannes-sasongko!
this really works. so what i do now is:

```
# save original package, e.g.: 'Gtk2::Image'
my $ref = ref $widgets[0]; 

# get the id
my $id = ( bless $widgets[0], "Gtk2::Buildable" )->get_name;  

# restore package
bless $widgets[0], $ref;
```

this is kind of a hack, but it works. better/cleaner solutions welcome!

Answer (score 0):

$widget->Gtk2::Buildable::get_name() should do the trick if you need the name of widget